# What do you call a day that never comes?

Tags: expressions

Searching on Google Books I discovered that 'a day that never comes' has 2.060 results.

As an example usage, among a lot of others, in 'Healing Words' by Susan Brozek it is written:

> If we wait until we feel like obeying, we will be waiting for *a day
>   that never comes*!

I would like to know whether there is a short phrase or expression to refer to *a day that never comes*.

I focused my attention on 'a never day', but, checking for this phrase, I didn't found anything confirming it is a common usage.

Thus, what do you call   *a day that never comes*?

Comment: The 12th of never, when hell freezes over, When Godot gets here, 'never today, always tomorrow'.

Comment: I would call it *tomorrow*...

Comment: Tomorrow never comes.

Comment: Why downvotes and closevotes! Should I have asked this question *tomorrow*?

Comment: Upvoted - as no reasons given for downvoting.

Comment: There's a bunch of synonyms here: http://thesaurus.com/browse/forever

Comment: @user814064 the OP is searching for words to describe a day that never comes, how is _forever_ relevant?

Comment: @terdon If we wait until we feel like obeying, we will be waiting forever. Since I posted that link, people are posting answers below that are on that page.

Comment: *Pig fly day!!*

Comment: @Atsuto, are you looking for a term with in-built ridiculousness? Sadness / ennui? Neutrality?

Comment: "now or never" ... "waiting for never" ...

Answer (score 6):

The commonest idiomatic phrase for this is

> When Hell freezes over.

I have to say I loved [@Wayfaring Stranger's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126828/what-do-you-call-a-day-that-never-comes#comment261685_126828) *when Godot gets here* but I doubt it will be widely understood. I often use *the 30th of February* but it is not an idiomatic phrase as such.

Comment: We should also mention "when pigs fly" and others. It frame the question; should the word express ridiculousness? Expressions like these have an inherent absurdity that other terms do not. Interesting

Comment: They said America would have a black president when pigs fly. Obama became president, and Swine Flu.

Answer (score 4):

English has a term:

> "**epagomenal**"

e.g. an [epagomenal day](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epagomenal).  It's an adjective, though – from the Greek root *epagein*.

[It refers to a "day out of time"](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mclennan/BA/FDOT.html).  We mostly use it to mean an intercalation day, but its origin is regarding a **mythic day** that *does not and cannot occur in the time we experience*.  These were days reserved for gods and the like, and as such those days never did come for mortals.

---

I have heard speakers of Español use the word "**Mañana**" in this way.

it is not the only way to use 'mañana' - the word's most-basic meaning is 'tomorrow'.  But there is a [*sad* usage](http://us.toluna.com/opinions/742462/I-will-manana-manana-never-comes-know-what.htm) of it in this way — said with *longing* — that expresses that suggests the idea that **[tomorrow will never come](http://returnoftheexpat.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/manana-never-comes/)**.  It is implied or inferenced [in many contexts](http://thefaintofheart.wordpress.com/2013/02/23/when-manana-never-comes/).

> When will my suffering end?  Mañana, my friend.  *Mañana*....

It's the best fit for what you're looking for, I think.

Pardon that's not an English answer.

Comment: Could you give a reference and definition for this usage of _epagomenal_? Also, I would understand _mañana_ to simply mean _in the future_ or _eventually_ not _never_.

Comment: Of course; a google search returned both my examples in the first results.  Remember you can always check google if something sounds unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I had and I did not find it which is why I asked. In any case, the whole point of answering here is so we don't _need_ to search Google. Anyway, The M&W link you gave does not work for me because I don't have a subscription (that was the page I had found and the main reason I asked you for the definition). The second link just uses the term as _days that don't exist_ and _not_ as days that never come.

Comment: Interestingly, M-W asks for money only if linked from another site.  if you went to it through google then it's free.  huh.   Also, *days that don't exist* cannot come

Comment: I am not contesting the term, I just have not seen it used this way which is why I asked for a reference. I thought it was interesting and it was a word I did not know and the meaning in modern Greek is very different. The only definition I found in my cursory Google search was the M&W site which defines it as _intercalary_ and explains that he full definition (which presumably supports your usage of the word) is only available to paying subscribers. In any case, adding definitions and references for any usage is considered good form here so I asked for one.

Answer (score 2):

***Tomorrow never comes***

> Prov. When the day arrives that you are now calling "tomorrow," you will call that day "today" and a different day will be called "tomorrow." (Therefore, you should not resolve to do something tomorrow, since that day will never arrive.) *Jill: When are you going to go to lunch with me? Jane: Tomorrow. Jill: Tomorrow never comes.*

This is a very common idiom, apparently American in origin (the Freedictionary).

Answer (score 1):

Eternity is one word that's often used

Answer (score 1):

There are various localised phrases, but my favourite is *the Greek Calends* (Calends being a Roman date, an equivalent might be 'till the Buddhist Christmas').

Answer (score -1):

***Someday***, maybe.

(+ characters)

Answer (score -2):

Would you consider the following words?

***unrealised***

***imaginary***