# What are phrases for the a date meaning "never"?

Tags: dates

What are current expressions/phrases for a date or point in time in the future that does not exist, meaning "never"? In German, we have "St. Nimmerleinstag" (meaning "the day of saint never"), what would be comparable English expressions?

Comment: "When pigs fly" https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/phrases/when-pigs-fly/ -- "The twelfth of never" (This and other alternatives are given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_idioms_of_improbability)

Comment: **'When hell freezes over'**. 

Comment: +1 @Greybeard It's not for nothing that your beard has turned grey.

Comment: Not in a **month of Sundays**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of Persian idiom "When the reed blooms"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318185/what-is-the-equivalent-of-persian-idiom-when-the-reed-blooms) 'When hell freezes over', 'when Burnham Wood comes to Dunsinane --Shakespeare', 'on February 30th'  and many other suggestions are listed.

Comment: A character on a TV show I was watching tonight pretended to check his diary and said he could do the thing being asked of him from "the 7th of never through to the 15th of ain't-gonna-happen".